# Getting rid of the tiny line of space below my footer image

Tags: html, css

[image: Image here]

The wooden plank with drop shadow is my footer image. The lighter shade of brown around it is my background image.

There's a tiny line of space in between the plank and the background at the bottom. I want to remove it to make the plank align exactly at the end of page.

When I tried adding `border: 2px solid red` to check, there's a tiny amount of padding which is causing the little space.

Are there any ways to clear it ? Thanks.

CSS:

```
#footerBg {
position: relative;
bottom:-63px;
left:-50px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<footer>
            <figure id="footerBg">
                <img src="images/BG_F_S3.png" alt="Footer Background" width="" height="" />

            </figure>   

        </footer>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding vertical-align: top to the image?

Comment: If you don't post some of your code (html and/or css) we can only guess. Try to provide a minimal example where the problem shows up.

Comment: why not create a fiddle and post here ?

Comment: Hmm somehow setting `#footerBg img {
 display: block;
} ` seems to remove the tiny line of space. IS this the correct method ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting `display: block;` in the page stylesheet for your `img` tag. I prefer this method, and it seems to be the most widely used.

You can also use `line-height: 0;` on your image container, or set `vertical-align: bottom;` on your `img` tag. I also see people suggesting that you use `vertical-align: sub;`, but this won't work in IE6 or IE7.

The solution will look something like this fiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/NdNGv/2/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my site(little line). Problem was in **line-height** attribute of inner div's, it **SHOULD NOT** be greater or equal to parent's height;

Answer (score 0):

Could be padding on container, or margin on an inner element?

Any floats in/near footer?

Might need to post HTML and CSS for better answers...